# Is this a flaw in my function or of docx.Document in Python

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using docx.Document to extract some highlighted texts/words in a docx file, but the result is very perculiar becuase some words extracted were broken into pieces， like this:

```
['sniffle', 'irritations', 'enzymes', 'abrasive', 'immunoglobulins', 'histamine', 'leukotriene', 'predisposition', 'an', 'aphylaxis', 'syndrome', 'angioedema', 'contact', 'dermatitis', 'frightening', 'tingling', 'eczema', 'nausea', 'wheezing', 'anaphylaxis', 'lump', 'epinephrine', 'venom sac', 'scrape', 'ointment', 'hydrocortisone', 'calamine', 'loose-fitting', 'swatting', 'birch', 'fact sheet', 'urticarial', 'A', 'ngioedema']
```

'an', 'aphylaxis' are actually from one word 'anaphylaxis', 
'A', 'ngioedema' are actually from one word 'Angioedema'

I did not highlight the two words in a wrong manner, like highlight 'A' first, then 'ngioedema', which is absurd.

The logic is very simple: 
   open the docx --> 
   use paragraphs/runs to go through the text --> 
   save highlighted words in a list

```
def preProcess(filepath):
    document = docx.Document(filepath)
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        for run in para.runs:
            if run.font.highlight_color == WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW:
                keyText.append((run.text.lstrip()).rstrip())
                for key in keyText:
                    if '' in keyText:
                        keyText.remove('')
    extractWdFrmDocx(keyText)
```

Apparently, when extracting, a word cannot be broken

Comment: you can note that `anaphylaxis` is extracted twice and there is only problem first time. Try to identify difference between two cases. Can you provide sample docx that demonstrate the problem? Is it possible there are some non-prinitig chars in the first case, e.g. maybe long word is broken on two lines?

Answer (score 0):

The text in a paragraph can be broken into runs at arbitrary points, and a single word spanning multiple runs is a common occurrence. Consequently, there is no guarantee that runs occur at word boundaries. If you want to extract highlighted words you will need a more sophisticated approach.

One approach is to split `paragraph.text` into words such that you also know the starting offset of the first character of each word within the run. Then you can traverse the runs to identify those that have highlighting, accumulating the offset of the start of each run.

You'll need some clever logic in there to identify which words are in highlighted runs, but all the information mentioned should be all you need to do that.

So for a paragraph with text "a highlighted word", your word offsets would be:

```
(0, "a"), (2, "highlighted"), (14, "word")
```

and your highlighted run (offset, length) pairs might be:

```
(2, 4), (6, 7)
```

From this you could calculate that the first character of `(2, highlighted)` was highlighted and that highlighting was continuous through the remainder of the word.

You may be able to simplify your logic to select any whole word where the first character is highlighted and not worry about runs that start in the middle of a word, depending on your needs.